# Android Preview effect video on TexttureView

Tags: preview, effect

I have some problem with preview effect on view extends TextureView.
I using ScalableVideoView (Created by yqritc on 2015/06/11.) To show center crop video. Now I want preview effect on this video.
I tried to find some demo for this.

Could anybody give me some advice on this?

Comment: Please try to improve this question by showing us your best good faith attempt and by asking a much more specific question over just what confuses you. So please, give it a try.

Comment: Hi.
Step 1 : I record a videos portrait 10s.
Step 2 : I using : https://github.com/yqritc/Android-ScalableVideoView to preview this video on square frame. This lib using a view extends TextureView to play videos.
Step 3 :  I want preview effect like mono ,  blur , etc..
I have a example preview effect on videos but that code only support preview on a view extends GLSurfaceView.
Thanks.